# How to hide all elements in android listview except header?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a simple listview with a header and a dynamic number of elements (can be from 0 - 20).  I am looking for a method on how to hide all elements but leave the header visible.

I've tried searching on SO but have only found methods to hide the whole list or to hide the header, but nothing to do the inverse.

Comment: can you explain it with code?

Answer (score 0):

This post may answer you question.

**ListView with ability to hide rows**
http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/01/listview-with-ability-to-hide-rows.html